# Javascript to change li tag text

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I am using the following HTML:

```
<li id="item1" data="icon: 'base.gif', url: 'page.htm', target: 'Page'">Item 1 Title</li>
```

I am trying to change the **Item 1 Title** part to something else.

I have tried using:

```
document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = "Item was changed";
```

but had no luck. Even tried using:

```
document.getElementById("item1").value = "Item was changed";
```

but still no luck.

I am only wanting to change the text and leave eveything else the same.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `innerHTML` should work just fine http://jsbin.com/abaxuw/1/edit

Comment: Could you paste the complete code that has both HTML and JS. I think somehow you are running JS before DOM is ready.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Could also be duplicate IDs, but that's just another guess

Comment: @D.Strout right. In fact nothing can be said without complete reproducible source.

Comment: <ul>
<li id="item1" data="url: 'reader.htm', target: 'AccessPage', reader: '1'">Reader 1</li>
</ul>
I am running the following code in a Function that is called as soon as the page loads. I know the function is running as I have added a Alert box to confirm.

Comment: Please add the **complete** code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = "Item was changed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function and all it after the page is loaded

```
var changeText = function(text){ 
    document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = text;
}

window.onload = function() { 
    changeText(' some text '); 
 }
```